# I'm using Laravel 10, socket.io and I want to see online users in console.log in welcome.blade.php , but it doesn't show anything, why?

Tags: laravel, events, socket.io, vite, laravel-echo

Laravel echo server is running successfully I created an event and a listener. The commands I use are; npm run vite , php artisan server , laravel-echo-server start (also redis-start ) , php artisan queue:work.
These work without any problems and when I make a request with postman, I can see laravel-echo-server start in the terminal I started without any problems, with the following name:
[image: In Terminal]
[image: that's queue:work]
[image: Redis-cli monitor]
I added laravel_database_ prefix in my redis settings. then after importing window echo in app.js. I can see the output with console.log(window.echo) in blade.
but later welcome.blade.php   `window.Echo.channel('online_users').listen('UserStatusUpdated', (event) => {`  command does not enter the blog. I couldn't get the output of the online users id and isOnline fields in console.log, can you help?
app.js

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
window.io = io;
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host:  'http://127.0.0.1:6001/', // Laravel Echo Server'ın adresi
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'], // WebSocket ve Secure WebSocket

});
```

welcome.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta  charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Online Users</title>
    {{-- @vite(['resources/js/app.js']) --}}
    @vite(['resources/js/app.js'])
</head>
<body>

    <h2>Online Users:</h2>
    <ul id="online-users">
        <!-- Online users will be displayed here dynamically -->
    </ul>


<script>
 window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
        if (window.Echo) {
            console.log(window.Echo);
            window.Echo.channel('online_users').listen('UserStatusUpdated', (event) => {
                console.log("Received UserStatusUpdated event:", event);
                const onlineUsersList = document.getElementById('online-users');
                const listItem = document.createElement('li');
                listItem.textContent = event.isOnline ? 'User is online' : 'User is offline';
                onlineUsersList.appendChild(listItem);
            });
        } else {
            console.log("Echo is not loaded yet. Waiting...");
        }
    });
```

Event
[image: UserStatusEvent]
Listener
[image: Listeneer]
and that my controller method

```
   public function updateUserStatus(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        if (!$user) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'User not authenticated'], 401);
        }
        try {
            $user->is_online = !$user->is_online;
            $user->save();
            event(new UserStatusUpdated($user->id, $user->is_online));
            return response()->json(['message' => 'User status updated successfully', 'is_online' => $user->is_online]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Error updating user status'], 500);
        }
    }
```

I searched a lot but couldn't find the right solution for me

Comment: I'm assuming you don't have a route for the channel so the user just doesn't get authorized. What do you have in routes/broadcast.php?